# Changing author / title info of an existing PDF not working

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I am using PDFBox v2.0.26 to modify existing PDFs that were produced with PrinceXML and then merged with the CLI of PDFBox.

Afterwards I want to update the PDF's meta data, among it author and title using a Java script. This is not quite working. When I open the PDF after post-processing, I cannot see the new author and title info, but it is there (somewhere), because when I read it back I get the new values.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open Adobe Acrobat Pro DC (I'm using version 2022.002)
2. File > Create > Blank page
3. Ctrl D > enter words for author and title (e.g. "author here" and "title here")
4. Close dialogue and save document
5. Run the code below
6. Output on first run:

```
Existing author: author here
Existing title: title here
```

Output on second run:

```
Existing author: My new author
Existing title: My new title
```

When I open the PDF in Acrobat and do Ctrl-d I see:

```
Title: title here
Author: author here
```

What am I missing? It works well if I create a new PDF from scratch, just not with existing PDFs.

My code:

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException; 
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocumentInformation;

public class setTitle {
   public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

       String filepath = "C:\\Temp\\temp.pdf";
    
       //Loading an existing document 
       File file = new File(filepath); 
       PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file); 
     
       //Creating the PDDocumentInformation object 
       PDDocumentInformation pdd = document.getDocumentInformation();
    
       System.out.println("Existing author: " + pdd.getAuthor());
       System.out.println("Existing title: " + pdd.getTitle());
       
       //Setting the author of the document
       pdd.setAuthor("My new author");
       
       // Setting the title of the document
       pdd.setTitle("My new title"); 
       
       //Saving the document 
       document.save("C:/Temp/temp.pdf");
    
      //Closing the document
      document.close();
    
   }
}
```

Comment: You need to change the XMP metadata as well, see the `PrintDocumentMetaData` and `AddMetadataFromDocInfo` examples. I'll do something at another time unless someone else does it first.

Comment: Correct. When Adobe Reader sees a field (such as Title) in both the XMP metadata and the old-fashioned metadata, it prefers the XMP field. Other readers may behave differently. For the author, you may need to update the `pdf:Author` field and the `dc:creator` field if both are present. For title, you may need to update `pdf:Title` and `dc:title` if both are present.

Comment: My comment mentioned the wrong example, it's not `PrintDocumentMetaData`, it's `ExtractMetadata`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
PDDocumentCatalog catalog = document.getDocumentCatalog();
PDMetadata meta = catalog.getMetadata();
XMPMetadata metadata;
if (meta != null)
{
    DomXmpParser xmpParser = new DomXmpParser();
    metadata = xmpParser.parse(meta.toByteArray());
}
else
{
    meta = new PDMetadata(doc);
    catalog.setMetadata(meta);
    metadata = XMPMetadata.createXMPMetadata();
}
DublinCoreSchema dcSchema = metadata.getDublinCoreSchema();
if (dcSchema == null)
{
    dcSchema = metadata.createAndAddDublinCoreSchema();
}
dcSchema.setTitle(pdd.getTitle());
dcSchema.addCreator(pdd.getAuthor()); // you may want to check whether the author is already there

XmpSerializer serializer = new XmpSerializer();
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
serializer.serialize(metadata, baos, false);
meta.importXMPMetadata(baos.toByteArray());
```

Comment: if this doesn't work, please share your PDF file.

Comment: Thank you Tilman for your tireless and quick support. If I keep the 'if' part when meta is not null I get ```Exception in thread "main" org.apache.xmpbox.xml.XmpParsingException: Failed to instantiate DateType property with value 2022-08-31T14:33:02+10:00 in xmp:CreateDate```. Commenting out the 'if' part but keeping 'else' throws no error.

Comment: Probably the stack trace from https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4967 . Add this to your pom.xml:

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>

Comment: Hi Tilman, currently my project is not using Maven or any other building tool. Is there another way to add the dependency? I do have a module-info.java.

Comment: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.3.1/jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar

Comment: Hi Tilman,
thank you. I have added the JAR to the list of external modules. Your code is working, however, most PDFs we are working with do not have an XPacket header for their XMP data which would throw an exception and prevent further processing. I have therefore commented out the if-statement (if meta is not null) and overwrite any existing data. I have also clarified the third parameter for the serializer and ensured it writes an XPacket tag: ```Boolean withXpacket = true; serializer.serialize(metadata, baos, withXpacket);``` . This is working now. Thank you so much for your help.